# ¿Cómo puedo realizar esta consulta en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, modelorelacional

Tengo la siguiente base datos muy pequeña

Personas

[image: Base de datos personas]

Tengo que obtener sólo el campo email, y sólo obtener el correo que contenga "hotmail"

He probado con la siguiente consula

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,',',1) AS email FROM personas WHERE email like '%hotmail%';
```

Pero sólo me devuelve sólo el primer email de las filas que contienen un email de hotmail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF( 
LOCATE(
    ',', 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@hotmail.com',1)
) > 0,
CONCAT( 
    SUBSTR( 
        email, 
        LOCATE(
            ',', 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                email,
                '@hotmail.com',
                1
            )
        ), 
        LOCATE(
            '@',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                email,
                '@hotmail.com',
                1
            )
        )
    ),
    '@hotmail.com' 
),
SUBSTR(
    email,
    1,
    LOCATE(
        ',',
        email
    ) - 1
)
) AS email FROM personas WHERE email like '%hotmail%';
```

Tal vez esto te pueda servir, sin embargo como consejo sería mejor que pusieras los correos separados en otra tabla como relación uno a muchos para que fuera más sencillo la búsqueda y devolución de datos

Answer (score 1):

Tu solución es casi correcta solo que toma al primer elemento de la cadena separada por coma, entonces lo que se tiene que tomar el ultimo solo aplicando -1 para que empiece del final. esto aplica solo si la coincidencia esta en el orden que tu estas presentando.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,',',-1) AS email FROM personas WHERE email like '%hotmail%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo recomendaría, más allá de forzar esta consulta, que normalizaras esta base de datos.

En lugar de tener todos los emails en un campo email en tu tabla de personas, lo mejor sería tener una tabla de emails, y cada una con una columna que tenga el ID del de la tabla personas, que eso también le hace falta a tu tabla.

Me tomé la libertad e hice unas tablas y también la consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE personas ( 
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    edad VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE emails ( 
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    id_persona INT(6) NOT NULL
); 


INSERT INTO `personas` (`id`, `nombre`, `edad`) VALUES (1, 'John', 20); 
INSERT INTO `personas` (`id`, `nombre`, `edad`) VALUES (2, 'Rosa', 10); 
INSERT INTO `personas` (`id`, `nombre`, `edad`) VALUES (3, 'Pedro', 15); 
INSERT INTO `personas` (`id`, `nombre`, `edad`) VALUES (4, 'Brandon', 18); 
INSERT INTO `personas` (`id`, `nombre`, `edad`) VALUES (5, 'Test', 20); 

INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (1, 'juan@gmail.com', 1); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (2, 'juan@hotmail.com', 1); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (3, 'rosa@hotmail.com', 2); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (4, 'pedro@outlook.com', 3); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (5, 'pedro@hotmail.com', 3); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (6, 'brandongs@outlook.com', 4); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (7, 't@g.c', 5); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (8, 't@k.c', 5); 
INSERT INTO `emails` (`id`, `email`, `id_persona`) VALUES (9, 'test@hotmail.com', 5);
```

Y luego de eso viene la consulta

```
SELECT email 
  FROM emails 
  inner join personas 
  where id_persona = personas.id and email like '%hotmail%';
```

Y esto da como resultado la lista de emails, que luego puedes recorrer uno por uno

```
juan@hotmail.com
rosa@hotmail.com
pedro@hotmail.com
test@hotmail.com
```